# How to import PCB outline into Eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I am designing a PCB in Eagle, however my PCB has a bit of a complicated shape which I can not design directly in Eagle.

I want to design it in a simple CAD software and would then like to import it into Eagle.

Is there any way to import a drawing from a CAD software into Eagle to use as the dimension for the PCB?

---

Comment: You can probably draw that in Eagle... That said, any vector handling software will do it, Illustrator, AutoCAD, Rhinoceros, Solidworks, Inventor, FreeCAD, etc

Comment: I see no problem to draw that thing in Eagle.

Comment: You should also be able to do it in Fusion 360

Comment: Thanks all.I worked with Pro-E, CATIA but I am new to Eagle CAD and Altium. I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Actually I have the PCB design in Altium. Can I take only the PCB layout to eagle?

Comment: It's not an entirely unreasonable question. I'm not sure why this has been so badly received.

Answer (score 8):

Eagle V6 and later can import a DXF file using the `importdxf` ULP.

If you export your outline as a DXF file you can then import it on to the dimension layer in Eagle.

Most CAD software will be able to export a DXF file, so pick one of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I have the DFX format. But I use Eagle 7.4.0 and I do not find any options to import DFX format in eagle board view in dimension layer.

Comment: @litunbls it's a ULP. If you click the ULP, and then find the file called `import-dxf`. Alternatively, type the command `run import-dxf`.

Comment: Eagle 8 has DXF import directly in the file menu (shortcut to the ULP)